# Format and return a string from a function in C

Tags: c, strings, formatting

> Write a function that will format a string and return it

A fixed length of string is malloc-ed. `snprintf` is used to format the string and then the buffer is returned.

```
const char *format_string(void)
{
    char *buf = malloc(128);
    snprintf(buf, 128, "%s/%d/%s/path", "here", 69, "is the");
    return buf;
}
```

`format_string()` can be later used like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *str = strdup(format_string());
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The task "format a string and return it" sounds silly and is way too unspecific to be of any use.

Answer (score 3):

regarding:

```
char *str = strdup(format_string());
```

The memory returned from `format_string()` is already allocated from the heap.   The posted code has two memory leaks.

1. the allocated memory in the function: `format_string()` is never passed to `free()`
2. the allocated memory in the function: `strdup()` is never passed to `free()`

suggest:

```
char *str = format_string()); 
printf("%s\n", str);
free( str );
```

The call to `malloc()` should be checked to assure it was successful.  Suggest:

```
char *buf = malloc(128);
if( !buf )
{
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Note: `perror()` is exposed in the header file: `stdio.h`

Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed in the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: Concerning "the allocated memory in the function: `format_string()` is never passed to `free()`". `buf` lives until it's content is being returned. I understand it stays unfreed. But how do I free `*buf`?

Comment: the pointer to the allocated memory is being passed back from: `format_string()` so, in `main()`, after calling `printf()`, call `free(  str );`  BTW: the pointer in `buf` is all that dies, the actual allocated memory is still allocated.

Comment: regarding: *and then the buffer is returned.*  No, the buffer is NOT returned,  Only a pointer to the buffer is returned

Answer (score 0):

`malloc`ed memory has to be `free`d at some point.  [`free()`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) needs a pointer to non-`const` data as argument.  Therefore, `format_string()` has to return a pointer to non-`const` data, so that it can be passed to `free()` later.